# Passing object to << overload in alters data in object in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to write a list class in C++, and I want to overload the `<<` operator. However, when I pass the list object to the operator function, changes the values within the object. Other questions on StackOverflow have not helped resolve this.
Superfluous code has been removed from the following:

LinkedList.h:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;

    LinkedList();
    void push(int data);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList& list);
};
```

This is LinkedList.cpp:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}

void LinkedList::push(int data) {
    Node newNode = Node(data);
    if (size == 0) {
        head = &newNode;
        tail = &newNode;
    } else {
        tail->next = &newNode;
        newNode.prev = tail;
        tail->next = &newNode;
    }
    size++;
}


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList& list) {
    os << "[";
    os << list.head->data;
    os << "]";
    return os;
}
```

(At the moment I just want it to output the data in the first element in the list)

Here is the driver code:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

int main() {
    LinkedList lis = LinkedList();
    lis.push(5);
    std::cout << lis;
}
```

Please be gentle, I'm new to C++.

Edits:
Sorry, here is Node.h:

```
#pragma once
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;

    Node(int data);
};
```

and Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(int initdata) {
    data = initdata;
    next = nullptr;
    prev = nullptr;
}
```

I have also added the rest of LinkedList.cpp. The output I had expected from the above code is `[5]`, since I am pushing 5 onto the list and then outputting it (or, at least, trying to).

Comment: What is `Node`? What is `LinkedList()`. What is `push`? Please [edit] and provide a [mcve], something that we can actually compile. Also tell us what output you expect and what output you get.

Comment: Too much superfluous code has been removed, because this code does not compile.  Or, not enough superfluous code has been removed yet, because this code does not compile.

Comment: We need to see the definition of `LinkedList()` and `push` in order to help you debug the memory corruption bug hiding in either or both.

Comment: You store the _address_ of a local variable here. `head = &newNode;`. Local variables are no longer accessible once they get out of scope.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't understand? ```head``` isn't a local variable, it's an attribute of ```lis```, so it should still be accessible with ```lis.head```, right? Or have I missed something? My debugger is telling me that there's no problem with the ```push``` function.

Comment: @dacox yes, you've missed the fact that  `newnode` is a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate new nodes with the `new` operator.

This is your corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node *prev;

  Node(int data);
};  

Node::Node(int initdata) {
  data = initdata;
  next = nullptr;
  prev = nullptr;
}

class LinkedList {
public:
  Node *head;                       // <<<<<<<<<<< change here
  Node *tail;                       // <<<<<<<<<<< change here
  int size;

  LinkedList();
  void push(int data);

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList& list);
};

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
  head = nullptr;
  tail = nullptr;
  size = 0;
}

void LinkedList::push(int data) {
  Node *newNode = new Node(data);   // <<<<<<<<<<< change here
  if (size == 0) {
    head = newNode;                 // <<<<<<<<<<< change here
    tail = newNode;                 // <<<<<<<<<<< change here
  }
  else {
    tail->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = tail;
    tail->next = newNode;
  }
  size++;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList& list) {
  os << "[";
  os << list.head->data;
  os << "]";
  return os;
}

int main() {
  LinkedList lis = LinkedList();
  lis.push(5);
  std::cout << lis;
}
```